# Change Text style in itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I want to make the font bold using itextsharp. below is my code

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
      iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont bf = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont(iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CP1252, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

      //  iTextSharp.text.Font font1 = new iTextSharp.text.Font("iTextSharp.text.Font", 10, Font.Bold);
      //FontFactory.GetFont("TIMES_ROMAN", 10, Font.Bold);

      iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10);
      //iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(9); 
      PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText, font));
      cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(240, 240, 240);                                  
      pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN` to `iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.TIMES_BOLD` or use any of the other documented ways to use a bold font.